# How to Initialize and close a TCPClient in different actions MVC.NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tcpclient

I'm trying to create an MVC.Net Controller, that will start a TCPClient, in one action. read the newest result in another action, and close the TCPClient in the last action. But I don't know where to start with this.

Should the TCPClient be an object of the class?

Here's some persudo code of how I think I need to start, but I cant seam to wrap my head around the idea, help would be appreciated

```
public class Foo : Controller
{
    TCPClient myClient = new TCPClient();

    public bool StartClient(string ip, int port)
    {
    }

    public string readMostRecentPacket()
    {
    }

    public bool StopClient()
    {
    }

}
```

I'm trying to avoid potentially DOSing a TCP connection, as create and closing the client in a single action starts refusing the connection when using this is an AJAX polling metaphor

Comment: Looks to me like you simply want a TCPClient running in the background.  You might find this useful: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you need to consider before you attempt this:

1. ASP.NET MVC Controllers are stateless. This means that each request will create a new instance of the controller and you will not be able to keep track of any state. Each controller action does not know anything about any previous controller action, even in the same function. This is because HTTP is stateless. You can keep track of state by using SessionState or Singleton or application cache or database or something else, but ASP.NET MVC will not keep track of things for you.
2. Multiple users will end up calling the same controller code (same web page) and you will end up with multiple instances of your code running. This could possibly introduce hard to track bugs in your code. Another way of saying this is that multiple threads calling the same code could cause serious issues.
3. If you do end up successfully implementing your approach, you will probably want to do some kind of connection or client pooling because creating network connections is expensive.

Here is one possible approach (please use caution as I have not tested or implemented this approach):

1. Create a static class that has a list or array of TCPCient objects that are static
2. All access to this class is synchronized or locked (please read - semaphore, monitor or mutex)

This static class will be a single instance in your application and you will need to prevent multiple threads/users from stepping on each other. You will need to request a TCPClient and keep track of it in the user's session. This way every subsequent request can lookup the TCPClient object and take any necessary action.

Pitfalls:

1. Multi-threading
2. Blocking - The TCPClient array/list may not be big enough when too many users load your web page.
3. Deadlocking
4. Out Of Memory errors
5. Etc.

Hope this helps. Good luck.